# jquery - selecting unique id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm new to jquery

i generated html div with php and give each them a unique id

```
<div id=div1>text</div>
<div id=div2>text</div>
<div id=div3>text</div>
...
```

the problem is, how I select specific div with jquery? usually i use this code to select an element

```
$('#id')
```

but I have to make alot of selector because each id is unique. Recently I used something like this

```
<div ... onclick=getElem(id)></div>

function getElem(id){
     var elem=$('#div'+id);
}
```

Is it good to use `onclick`?

Comment: yes. this is absolutely fine.

Comment: It might be fine from a technically point of view, but if you use jQuery, and handle most of the things by code, you should be consistent and also use event handling and callback assignments through code. If you start to put callbacks into html properties, you risk to loose control of what is where when code grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the group of divs

```
<div id="div1" class="someClass">text</div>
<div id="div2" class="someClass">text</div>
<div id="div3" class="someClass">text</div>
...
```

Then in javascript:

```
$('.someClass').click( function(event) {
    var ele = $(this);
    // ele is the element you clicked on
});
```

Comment: which one is faster, my 'onclick solution' above or your code? or perhaps the speed can be ignored?

Comment: I would say speed isn't an issue at this point. Get a solution going first, then optimise after you get the logic down.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your real use-case is, but you shouldn't need the IDs anyway. Give all elements you want to handle clicks for a class:

```
<div class="some-group"></div>
<div class="some-group"></div>
<div class="some-group"></div>
```

Then just watch for clicks on the group:

```
$('.some-group').click(function(){
// do something with $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: Uh... yeah you should use IDs.

Comment: Not for selecting a group of elements. I'm not suggesting not using IDs at all, I'm suggesting not using them all as selectors

Comment: What do you use IDs for besides selectors? IDs are fast, and make sense in a lot of cases even when there is a group. Unless there is an unknown number of elements, use IDs.

Comment: Representing a variable group of elements is the exact reasoning behind classes. IDs are meant for selecting specific dom elements. You *can* select every element in a group using its ID, doesn't mean you should. As far as selectors go, they're more performant but the overhead of forcing an ID to do a classes job...

Comment: Yes, of course. Still, if there are 3 elements (like #header, #content, #footer), then it still makes sense to select all 3 by id, instead of class.

Comment: Sure, I didn't infer three specific layout containers from his original example, he listed three divs sequentially numbered so I figured there could be three, or fifty.

Comment: Still, if you don't know what OP's talking about, don't go recommending things.

Comment: Considering the accepted answer made the same recommendation I'm comfortable in my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the div elements:

```
<div id="div1" class="myDivClass">text</div>
<div id="div2" class="myDivClass">text</div>
<div id="div3" class="myDivClass">text</div>
```

Then you can iterate each element if you need to operate on each item separately

```
$('.myDivClass').each(function(){
   // Process each item found that use the myDivClass 
   $(this).text("set a new text");
});
```

Or you can operate on all element at once

```
$('.myDivClass').text("set text on all elements");
```

This means that you can set a click callback to all using:

```
$('.myDivClass').click(function(){
  // Your click handler for ALL elements with myDivClass

});
```

or on each item separately, allowing to include some additional handling

```
$('.myDivClass').each(function(){
   // Here u could do some checks
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); // or $(this).prop('id') // depends on jquery version

   if(id !== "div1"){
      $(this).click(function(){
        // Click handler for each item
      });
   }
});
```